# Spring data JPA + Native query - replace query string depending on profile

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-repositories

I have service:

```
@Service
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {

    private final MessageRepository smevMessageRepository;
    private final Environment environment;

    public MessageServiceImpl(MessageRepository messageRepository, Environment environment) {
        this.messageRepository= messageRepository;
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Message> findReadyToSend() {
        if (environment.acceptsProfiles("postgre")) {
            return messageRepository.findReadyToSendPostgre();
        }
        return messageRepository.findReadyToSendOracle();
    }
```

And It is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, String> {

    @Query(value = "select sm.* from MESSAGES sm ...", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> findReadyToSendOracle();

    @Query(value = "select sm.* from MESSAGES sm ...", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> findReadyToSendPostgre();
```

If I start spring boot server with `oracle profile` I call `findReadyToSendOracle` method and if `postgre profile` - `findReadyToSendPostgre` method. It work. But this solution is bad. I think. Because I write hardcode for profile check.  and my repository has 2 methods for different DB.

How to implement this correctly?

Comment: The correct way is  - you should build requests to database in vendor-independent way.
Could you show your native queries to revisit whether it's possible to re-write them more generic way?

Comment: @star67 Ok try `select sm.*
from MESSAGES sm
where sm.delivery_finished = 0
  and (sm.last_sent_date is null or EXTRACT(SECOND FROM now() - sm.last_sent_date) * 24 * 60 * 60 > sm.delay)
  AND sm.STATUS = 'REQUEST_READY'
order by COALESCE(sm.last_sent_date, to_date('2000.01.01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))` do you really think i would be so tormented if it were possible to solve it with the JPQL?

Answer (score 3):

What are the problems you are facing while adapting to JPQL? Using native/custom functions? It might look way too difficult, but you might find a way using criteria + the function *function* from JPA 2.1+, take a look at [this article](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-call-custom-function-criteriaquery/).

On the other hand, I found an old workaround of mine here that might help. There is a simple way to solve that using a few shortcuts with the @Profile annotation and some extra interfaces.

If you provide an interface with your expected native query method that extends JpaRepository, like this:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, String>{

    List<Message> findByReady();

}
```

Note the `@NoRepositoryBean`, avoiding duplicate beans with profile specialization.

Then, just provide your implementations according to your needs:

```
@Repository
@Profile("oracle")
public interface MessageOracleRepository extends MessageRepository {

    @Query(value = "select m.* from Message m where m.ready = false", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> findByReady();

}
```

... and ...

```
@Repository
@Profile("mysql")
public interface MessageMySQLRepository extends MessageRepository {

    @Query(value = "select m.* from Message m where m.ready = true", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> findByReady();

}
```

Now you will only need to provide the desired profile, inject and use the correct native queries.

As you can see I simplified the queries, for the sake of simplicity. Take a look at this [repository](https://github.com/dblsilverio/stackoverflow-52662612) with the adapted code.